# XL Fortran set permissions on Bluegene

Tags: permissions, fortran, chmod, mkdir

I am working on IBM Bluegene/Q system and I would like to create a folder using Fortran. Since Bluegene does not allow for the usual "call system" I have to resort to their intrinsic function:

```
CALL mkdir ("/home/luc/testfiles\0", %val(755))
```

as show here: https://wiki.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/2/23/Bgqfcompiler.pdf

This creates the folder, but the permissions are all wrong. How do I create a folder with the proper permissions on IBMs Bluegene/Q system? All their documentation is horrific and I could not find a working example.

Comment: It seems that BlueGene only has XL Fortran version 14 while execute_command_line is as supported since IBM XL Fortran 15.3 for AIX and Linux.

Comment: Please describe what is "all wrong". What exactly happened? Which permissions did you want? Which did you get? On which filesystem?

Comment: `ls -lah ` yields `d-wxr----t  2 jias1217 jias12 4.0K Jun 27 08:29 test` and I would like 775 or similar, such that I can access the folder afterwards.

Comment: BG's aren't running a "normal" OS on the compute nodes anyway, at least to my knowledge, so even if it were there the argument to execute_command_line may well have to be modified, assuming the OS has appropriate support for the operation required

Comment: @IanBush I am trying to use the BG intrinsic fortran functions, such as mkdir (p. 59 http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247948.pdf), but setting the permissions for me does not work with these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mkdir is a POSIX function implemented in the C library.  You can find its documentation here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html.  You can find the values for the mode / permissions argument of mkdir here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html#tag_13_62.  Notice that the values are in octal.

What's relevant in this case is that the value you're providing for the second argument is wrong.  You're passing decimal 755, which is octal 1363.  The example in the manual passed decimal 448 which is octal 0700.  If you want octal 0755, you should pass decimal 493.  (Or you can pass %val(o'0755'))